# What's the difference between "Bug" and "Glitch"?

Tags: terminology

I heard about 2 terms defining a game error: "Bug" and "Glitch".
**What's the difference between them?**

Comment: a bug is something that causes even some hardened soldiers to become squeamish, while a glitch is a character that cannot leave its game.

Comment: [Meta question about migrating this to English SE.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11334/108003)

Comment: I loved reading all the answers bellow. Sadly none of them gave a really good example of something that I would consider a Glitch and not a Bug, so I'd like to give an example easy to understand. Continue on next comment with an easy to understand example....

Comment: Lets say we have a browser based game, so said game needs to support several Browsers. Lets say in FF and Chrome game runs perfect, but when you have the page zoomed (90-%) for example some element or object of the game is displaying incorrectly only on Chrome. I wouldn't call this a Bug but rather a Glitch that only happens on zoomed out Chrome. Ultimately the programmer of the game will need to identify if the underlying issue lies on the game-side or on the Browser side, but in the end, he will need to add new code to support such situation, rather than correct a defect/bug on current code.

Answer (score 153):

## Highly non-technical answer:

I would say they are *effectively* interchangeable, though there tends to be a nuance in the way they are used:

The word **bug** is usually used when an *intended* game state is *not achievable*, due to an unforeseen issue in the game's code. i.e., you are unable to complete a level (or a boss doesn't spawn, etc.) due to an error in the code.

The word **glitch** is usually used when an *unintended* game state is *achievable*, due to an unforeseen issue in the game's code. i.e., you are able to clip through the ground (or advance to a part of a quest that normally requires more objectives to be met) due to an error in the code.

Additionally, "glitch" is used to refer to issues with graphics and sound in a way that "bug" almost never is.

Comment: Additionally, "glitch" is used as a verb much more commonly than "bug" is. It would be normal to say things like "the game glitched out on me", or "you can glitch through the door by dismounting a vehicle next to it". "The game bugged out on me" would be rarer, and "bug" is never used as a verb to describe actions taken by the player.

Comment: It'd be great if you could put in some definitions, or any evidence at all. I've never heard these used this way, and so have downvoted what currently appears to be an incorrect opinion.

Comment: @user2357112 The "game bugged out" sounds like a common set phrase to me.

Comment: The comment about 'bug' not applying to graphics is ridiculous. Google graphics bug and you'll find endless results. I don't understand how this is still getting upvotes. I have to assume it just sounds truthy.

Comment: @Timelord64: But, the gaming world does not differentiate these terms either.  As far as I can tell, this answer is completely made-up _(along with every other answer, the words are literally synonymous)_.  I have no idea why this question/answer are getting so many upvotes.

Comment: @Timelord64: He doesn't provide separate definitions. He provides separate _nuances_, which is accurate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion, please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) for that!

Answer (score 104):

I don't see one answer with sources so far, although perhaps that will change after I post this.

### In General

**Glitch and Bug are essentially synonymous**, but some groups will draw different, subtle differences depending on context. The most common theme among these differences is that **glitches are sudden, or temporary**, and the most common manifestation of this theme is that **bugs are mistakes in code, while glitches are the behavior that results from those mistakes**.

To illustrate this, here are the definitions of [Glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch) and [Software Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug) from Wikipedia:

> A glitch is a short-lived fault in a system. It is often used to describe a transient fault that corrects itself, and is therefore difficult to troubleshoot.
>
> A software bug is an error, flaw, failure or fault in a computer program or system that causes it to produce an incorrect or unexpected result, or to behave in unintended ways. Most bugs arise from mistakes and errors made by people in either a program's source code or its design, or in frameworks and operating systems used by such programs, and a few are caused by compilers producing incorrect code.

Note that a glitch is described as "transient". Also note that the glitch is the fault itself, whereas a bug might refer more to the code that causes the fault, which is less transient than the actual fault.

### Common Usage Definitions

Here are some dictionary definitions of glitch and bug, to illustrate how similar these terms are in common usage.

**MW**

> **[glitch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glitch)
>
>   1 a :**  a usually minor malfunction *;* also: bug
>   **2 b :**  a minor problem that causes a temporary setback :  snag
>
> **[bug](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bug)
>
>   2 :** an unexpected defect, fault, flaw, or imperfection

Note the use of 'temporary' to describe a glitch, but also note that an alternate definition is simply 'bug'.

**TheFreeDictionary**

> **[glitch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glitch)
>
>   1.** A minor malfunction, mishap, or technical problem; a snag: a computer glitch; a navigational glitch; a glitch in the negotiations.
>   **2.** A false or spurious electronic signal caused by a brief, unwanted surge of electric power.
>
> **[bug](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bug)
>
>   3. a.** A defect or difficulty, as in a system or design.
>   **b.** *Computers* A defect in the code or routine of a program.

Note the idea of a brief surge of power in one of the glitch definitions, but also note how general the first definition is, and how it is essentially the same as a 'defect'.

Those who have always known of a certain distinction between 'glitch' and 'bug' as being the "correct" one should note these dictionary definitions, and keep them in mind when speaking to someone outside of whatever sub-culture or profession makes that distinction. The person you're speaking with may regard the terms as *completely* synonymous.

### In Gaming

These terms are used in gaming, as gaming involves software, and software involves bugs. Some subtle distinctions specific to this context can be made, but - as you can see from the other answers here - there's no real consensus on what those distinctions should be. So, it's the same general situation, where 'glitch' is more *likely* to mean the manifestation of a bug at run-time, and 'bug' is more *likely* to refer to the issue in the actual code.

Wikipedia's Glitch page has a section entitled [Video game glitches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch#Video_game_glitches). This section treats the terms as interchangeable:

> Glitches/bugs are software errors that can cause drastic problems within the code, and typically go unnoticed or unsolved during the production of said software. ... Texture/model glitches are a kind of bug or other error that causes any specific model...

Comment: To round out/slightly correct glitch definition #2 from the Free Dictionary, a glitch in electronics is caused by a signal potentially having a random state when it should always be determinant.  Commonly, however, this is understood as a design flaw in the electronics and *not* something that is due to any sort of power fluctuation problem.  As I said in my other comment, though, that more technical definition is probably not used much by game developers since there is no particular reason for them to be aware of it (hence on a software level it will tend to be used as a synonym for "bug").

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever Thanks for that. I think this meaning probably contributes to the implication that a glitch should be a sudden or temporary event at runtime.

Comment: Feel I need to stress this at each interest; Thios answer is so wrong, that it would lead to failure, should you be looking at it from a dev point of review. **The question is literally a staple of game dev exam**. If your teacher asks you "whats the difference between x and y" and you say "nothing"; your going to have a bad day.

Comment: As a software developer, *I would suggest you keep to software developing and assume your not actually game developing*. This might take different meanings in general software. In game developing, the two terms are widely acknowledged as meaning very different things. **Pro tip: if you google "Game Dev #word# definition, two very different pages pop up.**

Comment: @Timelord64: I have no clue what's your problem with this. neither your examples seem to be fitting nor your arguments appear to have any ground. You can't complain about this SE page is about gaming but the answer is techi... Then go for closing op instead. Since it's not the answerers fault if OP asks something about "development" on the "games only" site as you described it. The actually accepted answer is incorrect. Since it is an non techanswer to an unintended explicit tech question. So just because this is the wrong place for that questions doesn't negate right and wrong for answers!

Comment: @Zaibis How is it an "unintended explicit tech question"? Why is this automatically about development? Developers (of which I am one, though not of games) don't have a monopoly on either term, and they're regularly used - perhaps with a different meaning - by gamers who aren't developers. Since this is a site about gaming, and not game (or any other kind of) development, an answer that addresses what they mean to gamers, not what they mean to developers, seems like it would be the most suitable.

Comment: @Timelord64 If you can cite a resource backing up your claim that these terms have very specific, well-defined meanings in the discipline of game development, I would be happy to add a note on that to the section about the use of these words in gaming.

Comment: I disagree that "bug" and "glitch" are synonyms. A glitch is a bug, but a bug is not necessarily a glitch. Or have you ever heard of the term "glitchtracker"? How about "security glitch"? Or "then the program glitched to the desktop"? "This glitch hung the whole system"?

Comment: @Fozi I can't say for sure I've heard all those. The only one that sounds particularly odd is "glitchtracker". I have sources in this answer. If you have a criticism, it would need to be one of 1) the sources aren't credible, 2) the sources are incorrect, 3) I've interpreted the sources incorrectly. Which one are you asserting?

Comment: @DCShannon It's 3): Your Merriam Webster link has no mention of the word "glitch". Your Free Dictionary link correctly identifies glitch as `A minor malfunction`, which is a type of bug. The fact that the wiki page for "video game glitch" links to "software bug" does not prove that they are synonyms. Again, a glitch is a bug, but not all bugs are glitches. I don't see any of your sources support your post.

Comment: @Fozi I figured you could type in glitch yourself at the top bar. I guess I can add two separate links for each dictionary. I don't think I made any reference to the "video game glitch" page links. Not sure why you're bringing that up. Each source directly supports the thesis, with notes on how they relate. The first two from Wikipedia describe each of the two things as nearly identical, but with an emphasis on the short-term for glitch. Same for the dictionary definitions. I'm not sure how I could be more direct about it. You do recognize those definitions are quite similar?

Comment: This question belongs on ELU; plus one for answering it as such. Here's my [relevant answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238463/is-there-any-word-for-the-opposite-of-a-bug-in-programming/238474#238474) there.

Comment: @Fozi actually no. A bug can manifest as a glitch, but not necessarily, and a glitch can be a bug, but not necessarily. There can be millions of silent bugs (logic errors) in a piece of software that never manifest (glitch) for the user, since the specific conditions to trigger the glitch never happen. And a glitch can be for example hardware failure, in which case they're not the effect of a bug in the code. Say the processor overheats and the system restarts due to a hardware design issue, then it's not specifically a bug in the code that causes the glitch.

Comment: @DCShannon you've drawn some incorrect conclusions from the dictionary entries. Glitch: A malfunction. Bug: A defect. So the glitch is an event (my player fell of the map), while a bug is the logic error that causes the glitch (the player character has poor hit detection). So a bug is a defect in the product that manifests as a glitch. They are not synonymous, one is just the cause of the other. This is what they mean to developers though, gamers might have construed their entirely own interpretations. But this is the technical meaning.

Comment: @Jan That meaning is what I say in my answer. The terms are used in a largely synonymous fashion by many people, including gamers. To the extent that there is a difference, it's that one is in the code and the other is the manifestation. That's what the answer says. Did you find it unclear, or just not read it?

Comment: @DCShannon The recent edit makes it a lot clearer, while I still have a tiny objection to the use of "synonymous". They can often be used interchangeably due to the implied meaning through context, but they don't mean close to the same thing. A bug (My electrical outlet is incorrectly installed) is very different from a glitch (My house burnt down). It's nitpicking, but if you want to be technically correct they're not synonyms at all.

Comment: @Jan I'm not trying to be technically correct. I'm trying to say how these terms are *used*. I'm glad you found the edit to be more clear. It was motivated by your interpretation.

Comment: @DCShannon You can still write that they're *often used interchangeably* and be technically correct, while saying that they're synonyms is not.

Comment: @DCShannon you finally beat timelord and prove him wrong at something, thank you so freaking much :)!

Answer (score 21):

A video game is a program, considering this, we have the following.

A **bug** is an error found in the development environment before the product is shipped to the customer. We're talking about code issues here mostly.

A **glitch** on the other hand is a way of saying **defect** on a video game environment. A defect is the difference between expected and actual result in the context of testing. As such a defect is the deviation of the customer requirement. This defect can lead to **failures**.

The relation between bug, defect and failure is a common topic on software testing studies, specially QA and also software development. Moreso, this is a common [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37029/difference-between-a-defect-and-a-bug-in-testing) in the area.

Now the relation stated between glitch and defect can be worked through their definitions. A **[glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch)** is a short-lived fault in a system. In this case a software system, namely a video game. A **[fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_(technology))** is defined as an abnormal condition or **defect** at the component, equipment, or sub-system level which may lead to a failure. Which is to to say that a fault is a general way of saying defect. So this means glitches, defects and faults are heavily related.

So this means a glitch is, most of the times, a product of a bug. Although a lot of people use bug to define problems within games, bugs should be used in a development environment as that's what the word defect is for, which, given what was stated earlier, we can associate with glitch.

Comment: This is a good explanation from a development standpoint

Comment: "A bug is an error found in the development environment **before the product is shipped to the customer**" ... I wish.

Comment: As a software developer, I would usually use these terms interchangeably, but to the extent that there is a s difference, this would be it.

Comment: The definitions on the wikipedia pages for [Glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch) and [Software Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug) seem to largely agree with this distinction, while at the same time occasionally conflating the terms in the body.

Comment: Downvoting for the developer view. Best not to assume gamers understand Dev jargon. Good answer if this was Game.Dev.SE

Comment: *A **bug** is an error found in the development environment before the product is shipped to the customer.* – You do not happen to be working in marketing, do you?

Comment: At my place of work we use "bug" to refer to errors in code found in development and "defect" refers to errors found in production as a result of bugs that were missed in development.

Comment: @NathanK And at my place of work we just use bug (internally, what we say to the client is another matter) the entire time. Delivering the product doesn't suddenly change the nature of the problem, which is that your code has a bug in it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Delivering the product does not change the nature of the problem, it changes the context of the problem. It's the code which has bugs, the application has defects, problems, issues, crashes, etc.., but not bugs. It just that over the time the concept has been started to be used on different contexts. It's up to the people to speak correctly or not, but in any case that just evolves the language.

Answer (score 15):

The difference between bug and glitch is more of a semantic one. The most common way these are interpreted is that a glitch usually has to do with the presentation of a product, while a bug is usually seen more as interfering with gameplay.

For example, corrupted audio and textures are usually seen as glitches. another thing that's usually labeled as a glitch is collision detection going wrong.

The term bugs is usually used for problems like certain enemies not working properly, an item not doing the right thing,...

There's also a linguistical difference: the term glitch is often used for neutral or even positive incidents, while the term bug is usually used for something that is objectively negative. For example, when speed runners use an unintended way to traverse an object, they usually call it a glitch.

The term glitch also is used fairly often outside of software, mainly for electrical engineering and TV broadcasting.

Finally, some people also get the randomness of the event involved: Bugs are considered deterministic: most of them can be reliably triggered when the right circumstances are met. Glitches, on the other hand, are much harder to trigger reliably.

Answer (score 15):

A bug is an undesired consequence caused by a fault in the programming, it can be repeated exactly by following all the same inputs which caused it the first time.

Corrected by editing program code.

A glitch is a more random undesired effect, usually hardware based, caused by eg. lightning strike, fluctuating power supply, a loose data connection, dust getting into magnetic readers ( this last one is very rare these days )

Remedied by better hardware maintenance, more robust power supply.  Military hardware is to some extent bomb proof.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, it is the correct answer.

Comment: Ditto -- the most technical definition of "glitch" is a specific hardware related event (usually in badly/mistakenly designed hardware).  However, in a gaming context it is probably used more subjectively; I would guess many/most programmers are actually ignorant of the electronics level definition of "glitch" since it is irrelevant to what they are doing.

Comment: +1 - this is the best answer so far. A bug is a reproducible problem with the software; a glitch is an individual instance of unexpected behaviour (often arising from a bug).

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far. They are not synonymous in my mind. Glitches often happen during transmission of data or when reading or writing it -- the data changes unexpectedly, usually due to a random fault.

Comment: The best answer so far. I would add that, on the context of videogames, a glitch is the "manifestation" of an undesired effect. Bugs causes glitches, but are all glitches caused by bugs? I don't think so. Think about NES games and their blinking problem for example. Or the famous tliting cartridge glitches. Probably they aren't caused by programming errors, but hardware issues.

Answer (score 8):

Other answers are claiming that bugs and glitches are differentiated by the response of the program, but I've never heard this distinction used in a technical context.  The distinction I've always used is that a bug is caused by a program executing correctly, but in a way the programmer does not want, while a glitch is a program which executes incorrectly (as in, differently to the actual instructions in the executable) for some reason.  The distinction here is that glitches are caused by the executing environment failing to properly execute the program - as an example, if a graphics card overheats and fails to correctly display graphics, that is a glitch.  If the program loads the wrong image to render under some unusual set of conditions in the code, that is a bug.

Most glitches cannot be easily repeated, and more importantly tend to have different effects depending on the specific condition - because of this, in just about every use case of specific "glitches", the person is actually referring to a bug.  For example, "glitched Pokemon" are caused by the program attempting to load a Pokemon from an index number that doesn't contain a Pokemon - this is the programmer's mistake.  In order to invoke this bug, at no point does the program execute incorrectly; rather, the programmers did not expect players to take the exact actions that must be taken to encounter the undefined Pokemon, and because of that the program exhibits correct but undesirable behavior when those actions are taken.

Comment: Speaking as a developer of software I have to agree: The difference between bug and glitch is the difference between cause and effect, and glitches often have environmental causes not related to software design flaws.

Answer (score 7):

**Bugs** are effectively different from **glitches**.

Glitches are ocasions where unforeseen mechanics collide and create something which wasn't intended to be provokeable.

Bugs on the other hand are issues with the coding itself, which was expected to behave differently.

---

**What are the differences explicitly?**

One example would be Open World Games. While buildings and the ground may appear solid, most of the times it's just a single layer, in order to improve performance. Let's imagine that there's an intended underground level acessible by a trapdoor, which places the character in a small room (which has the ground level above, and walls around, but 'empty' past the walls).

A **bug** would've been the game being programmed accidentally being able to acess the trapdoor in other points of the map, placing the character in the 'empty' zone out of the room.

**A glitch** would've been using features which were not considered to be tried, such as trying to ride a bike through the hole, as in when exiting you'd be on the other side of the wall. One instance of this is GTA San Andreas.

---

**Essentially,**

A bug would create an undesired game state due to an error in coding, while a glitch is able to exploit the current game state by abusing it's engine

---

Answer (score 7):

A glitch is a certain type of bug.

"Bug" is a general term for any kind of programming error or unintended behavior. Some types of bugs are:

- "Crash": a program does something illegal and irrevocable and the OS shuts it down.
- "Hang": a program gets into an endless loop and can not continue. It is stuck, but the OS has no reason to shut it down.

**A "glitch" is a bug that is neither a crash or a hang: The program continues to execute, albeit in a possibly invalid state.**

This can be recoverable (e.g. just a display error, or you move back out of the object that you were not supposed to be able to move through) or not (e.g. you fall off the bottom of the level).

It can also simply be an error in the display (e.g you don't see or see through some object or some polygon goes across the whole screen). It could be an error in some AI behavior, e.g. an enemy that is stuck at some object an is not able to move on.

Comment: That's a plausible distinction, but not one I'm familiar with. Can you cite any evidence that this usage has currency? Perhaps a definition somewhere, or an example of it being used this way by a reputable source?

Comment: @DCShannon [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug) seems to agree. I write software for a living. I fix bugs, not glitches. Crashes and hangs are never glitches, always bugs. Maybe you can cite evidence that "glitch" and "bug" are synonyms, as you state in your answer?

Comment: I have such evidence in my answer. I don't see how that article supports your argument. Perhaps you could cite the relevant portion and include it in your answer, as I've done in mine. The particular distinction you seem to be focusing on is that glitches don't hang the system. This would be in line with the nuance I highlight in my answer: glitches tend to be shorter term than bugs.

Comment: I don't agree with you at all. A bug is an incorrectly implemented program. A glitch is an instance of a negative or unintended state. They can overlap (in the case of when a bug causes a glitch), but some bugs don't yield any glitches, and some glitches have other causes than a bug.

Comment: In Infocom's Beyond Zork, I'd say that being able to sell the butterfly repeatedly is a bug; selling it enough times to make one's money balance go negative would cause a glitch.

Comment: As another developer I think this answer is closest to the truth. A glitch, in the context of software, is generally used to describe a type of minor issue affecting the behavior or display of a program. Anything you would call a glitch, would be the result of a bug in the software.

Comment: As a general observation, there seems to be a difference in the understanding of the meaning of this word among the software developers and the general population.

Comment: @Hagelt18: While most glitches are caused by bugs, they may also be caused by things such as unreliable storage media.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple Answer:-**

A bug is an error, flaw, failure or fault in a computer program or system that causes it to produce an incorrect or unexpected result, or to behave in unintended ways. Most bugs arise from mistakes and errors made by people in either a program's source code or its design, or in frameworks and operating systems used by such programs, and a few are caused by compilers producing incorrect code. A program that contains a large number of bugs, and/or bugs that seriously interfere with its functionality, is said to be buggy or defective. Reports detailing bugs in a program are commonly known as bug reports, defect reports, fault reports, problem reports, trouble reports, change requests and so forth.

**And**

A glitch is a short-lived fault in a system. It is often used to describe a transient fault that corrects itself, and is therefore difficult to troubleshoot. The term is particularly common in the computing and electronics industries, and in circuit bending, as well as among players of video games, although it is applied to all types of systems including human organizations and nature.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

A "bug" is unintended behaviour of a program/game. This can be a crash or a showstopper or anything else that is unforeseen.

A "glitch" is a bug that does not result in a crash or anything similar, but it does something the user/player can "profit" of.
Examples are unintended unlocks (ingame items or program features), places one can reach where one is invulnerable, duplicating items and so on.

Comment: I have to say that I don't agree with this definition. 1) Bugs don't always crash a program. 2) Your example of an unintended unlock could definitely be caused by a bug--if the software was written to only unlock something under certain conditions, and the unlock can be achieved without meeting those conditions, then the underlying code was written incorrectly--the definition of a bug! Similarly, if any of the code was written with the intent to prevent duplication, the ability of duplication to occur is a bug (whereas a particular instance of it is a glitch).

Comment: @ErikE if you read my answer carefully, i say that a glitch is a more specified version of a bug. Also, i do not say that a bug always results in a crash.

Comment: I agree with everything up until the specification of it being something a player can take advantage of. That is more specifically called an exploit. That's not saying a glitch couldn't be an exploit, but a glitch is not necessarily an exploit. The term glitch could apply to other types of bugs like minor display or animation issues. 

http://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_Super_Mario_Bros._glitches#Blue_Bowser_Glitch

Answer (score 2):

In electronics hardware, a bug comes from an actual bug getting caught in a component and causing a short while a glitch is an undesired condition that corrects itself.

So I would say that if your game crashes, it's a bug, if it wacks out for a second then goes on as nothing happened, then it's a glitch, and varying degrees of the two.

Essentially if the issue corrects itself it's a glitch, otherwise if it persists it's a bug. There's obviously a very large grey area here.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it in more layman's terms, I going to try and treat it in more of a cause-effect relationship between the two.

A glitch is more often than not an effect caused by an unforeseen bug. A much more recent example is the "G-Slide" of Call of Duty Black Ops 3. Timed correctly, a player was able to jump and slide creating a more boosted movement throughout the map. This should be considered a **glitch** which other have defined as the unintentional consequence of some action or combination of actions by an actor (player/ai/physics miscalculation).

A bug is more often considered to be mentioned with regard to more serious consequences in-game. A much more recent example is Fallout 4's game save corruption. This can be near-repeatable or a one-time instance over a very specific set of circumstances. **Bugs** as stated above exist in code errors or misunderstandings of what the machine is being told to do. A simple "bug" is not closing a file after it has been written to (Some "corrupted" saves are just data that is mixed in a certain way such as writing the alphabet forwards to a file and not closing it then writing half the same data backwards to the file and attempting to read the file the same way as though it was a-z instead of z-nn-z).

Hope that helps. Technically, my definitions are dependent on severity.

Comment: To keep it more "lamens"? What do you mean?

Comment: @AshleyNunn layman's terms: in words that someone who is not an expert can understand

Comment: So you're simply saying that bugs are more severe glitches?

Comment: Not really, I'm saying that my understanding is that a glitch is caused by a bug but a bug can also not lead to a glitch. holding the terms separately.

Answer (score -2):

The two terms are pretty interchangeable, but for the "political" ramifications of each.  A "Glitch" is an unexpected and potentially "out of our control" kind of error in an automated system or program or application or whatever the algorithm is being called.  In this scenario, the technical designers and maintainers of the system accept little or no responsibility for the problem.  A "Bug" on the other hand is an identified problem in how the system was "coded" and therefore use of this term implies that the problem was and/or is still under the control of the designers/maintainers of the system.  In a nutshell, the difference between bug and glitch has to do with spin doctoring and blamestorms.

Comment: glitches and bugs are both under complete control of the developer in today's game age. Heard of a "patch"? To fix bugs and attempt to remove glitch causing bug errors.

Answer (score -3):

I speak from my own perspective, which is how I personally learned the words.  Others are welcome to show agreement or disagreement.

## bug - technical terminology

As I understood a "bug", the word was taught in computer classes, and these classes taught me the history of the word.  An old computer (which was very large, possibly filling most of a large room, and probably using vacuum tubes) had a failure.  Investigation found the mechanical cause was from a moth.

Since then, the term "bug" was used for computer errors, and especially used by "software development" / "computer programming".  So, an error in a computer program is a bug.

Since software specifies to do the same thing when all inputs are the same, many bugs are commonly easy to reproduce.  Some bugs, like being little with fireballs in Super Mario Bros. 1 (NES), may be rather safe (after their effects are mastered).

## glitches

Glitches always have detectable effects.  For instance, if a software bug corrupts some data, I've never heard of such an error being referred to as a "glitch" until that data is used, at which point problems may occur.  If a player's attack does 25% extra damage, and that is wrong, then it is a mistake and is, therefore, an actual bug.  However, if the enemy would have died anyway, and the game doesn't display the amount of damage, then the end result is the same and there is no lasting impact, so it is not a glitch.

The first time I heard of "glitch" was referring to an 8-bit NES game.  It probably related to something that was particularly nasty, causing the software to be unusable.  (Maybe a character got moved and trapped, or the game just crashed.)  Regardless, I considered it to be when something got into a state of being "broken", particularly if it then remained broken.

Another characteristic for the term "glitch" is if the effect is caused by hardware issues, such as malfunctions caused by things like dirt on a cartridge, would be a likely cause of a glitch.  Software issues could also be described as a glitch if they caused an effect that seemed similar to hardware being broken.  For instance, if a character teleports, which might be the effect that is expected if RAM kept track of information wrong, or if incorrect data was read from ROM, then that would also indicate a glitch.

Glitches are quite often very unsafe, although software may be able to fix some glitches by overwriting problematic data (such as when re-initializing a level after a death, or loading a "saved" game data).

## Recap : examples

So when Sinistar gave a player less than zero lives, and then treated the number as 255 lives, the game was still able to run stable.  There was no threat of the game becoming unusable.  After the lives became 255, Sinistar behaved as expected, and the game would end if the "player" continued to lose all of the remaining lives.  So this bug did not represent a "glitch".  In contrast, if a bug in DOOM 2 led to an Archvile causing another creature to become invincible, the result was a glitch because the situation continued to remain broken as the enemy continued to be unattackable.  The resurrection placing the enemy in an incorrect plane was a bug, but the remaining situation represented the glitch.

## Recap : Summary

A bug is a design flaw, most commonly referring to an error in the instructions which we typically call "software".

Glitches refer to hardware errors, things that seem like hardware errors (like if a sprite becomes garbled), or something that has a lasting impact.  A non-impacting error is not a glitch.

## Fun side notes

Oddly, based on these definitions, this means that the moth in the old computer would have caused glitched behavior, and doesn't represent a "bug" based on the newer way that the word has been used.

Super Meat Boy has a character that has been named "Glitch Girl".

Comment: Why does this have a downvote?

Comment: The term "bug" was in use before that anecdotal moth. That _did_ happen, but it was _already_ a joke at that point. read more on [Harvard University's site on the Mark I computer](http://chsi.harvard.edu/markone/language.html).

Comment: Seems awfully odd to contend that the Sinistar lives issue was not a glitch.

Comment: @mattdm : More detail than what I've been officially taught.  Great!  Thanks.

Comment: @DCShannon : And I would find it odd/inappropriate  to classify that as a "glitch".  A bug, definitely, but not a glitch.  So we definitely disagree (which is why the rating system may be useful...  at the moment my score is zero, but I've actually received a number of up-votes... and also downvotes.)  Our mutual feelings of oddness have to do with some clearly different perspectives of these terms.  I think these differences were caused because these terms are not defined by any clearly recognized central authority that provides definitive definitions.

Comment: Even by the logic presented in your answer, I don't see how that's not a glitch. Getting 255 lives when I'm supposed to be dead is definitely a "detectable effect", and definitely has a "lasting impact", as you get to keep playing. I didn't upvote not because I disagree, but because it's not clear what you're trying to say.

Comment: Once the player has 255 lives, the rules of the game haven't changed.  You still die the same way.  The game isn't much less stable, causing lots of other weird side effects.  Like a game with temporary invincibility, once the effect wears off, there are lasting repercussions from all the enemies you killed, but the effect is done.  From that point on, the game is playing normally (where you are vulnerable).  With Sinistar's 255 lives bug, the impact on how the game operates is done.  No code is altered (overwritten), and the game plays normally.  Next death = 254 lives = game operating right

Answer (score -11):

Bug is a software error, ending in wrong results or freezing of the system.
Glitch is a created error to take over the system and run different code.

Comment: An error that allows to run other code or even take over the system is a *security hole*, not a glitch.